# index by name or by position in list / vector, which is faster?

Tags: r, list, vector, indexing

I am currently trying to optimise the speed of a physical model computation. The specificity of this model is that it uses **hundreds** of input parameters, all stored in a big named vector:

```
initialize = c("temperature"=100, "airpressure"=150, "friction"=0.46)
```

The model, while **iterating** hundreds of times, needs to access the parameters, possibly updates them, etc.:

```
compute(initialize['temperature'], initialize['airpressure'])
initialize['friction'] <- updateP(initialize['friction'])
```

This is the logic. However I wonder if this is really efficient to work like this. What happens behind an indexation by name, is it fast? Some ideas to change this logic:

- define each parameter as an independent variable in the environment?
  (but how to pass a a large number of them as argument of a function?
- have a list of parameters instead of a named vector?
- access each parameter by its index in the vector, like this:

  compute(initialize[1], initialize[2])

If I go with this last solution, of course I will loose the readability of the code (which parameter is actually initialize[1]?). So a way to go could be to define their positions first:

```
temperature.pos <- 1
airpressure.pos <- 2
compute(initialize[temperature.pos], initialize[airpressure.pos])
```

Of course, why didn't I try this and tested the speed? Well, it would take me hours to transform every location of parameters call in the script, that's why I ask before doing it.

And maybe there is a even more clever solution?

Thanks

Comment: Make a very small test case and try with `microbenchmark`. But I would be surprised if the differences were large enough to be meaningful (https://xkcd.com/1205/)

Comment: @RichardTelford yes folliwing your advice i tested a little benchmark with 100 assignents and a sum of 100 params. Operations on lists seems to be faster than vector. And indexing by names from a vector with single brackets seems the slowest. But i'm not sure if this way to go is really representative of what is happening in my model, i'm afraid it's oversimplified.

Comment: I found a few places to look that may be helpful. From what I can tell this is the initial function called when `[` is used [subset.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e614acedf66ab376229010d1e9b43968c153aa91/src/main/subset.c#L164).

Comment: @RichardTelford @joseph Wood, guys, you would be surprised, but replacing `initialize['some.param']` by `initialize[['some.param']]` divided the whole computation time by 2...!